# How to loop a list in reverse order and skip last element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, reverse

I know I can have `for i in x[::-1]:` to loop through a list in reverse order. But what if I want to skip the last element then traverse from high to low? `for i in x[-1:0:-1]` does not work

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
=> 4,3,2,1         #  desired

for i in x[-1:-1]:
    print(i)

# it does not work
```

Comment: You can use this: `x[-2::-1]`

Comment: quick question anyway to use shortand for if elif statement without else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to begin from `-2` as `-1` starts from the last element:

```
for i in x[-2::-1]:
    print(i)
```

Alternatively, you can use `reversed` with list slicing:

```
for i in reversed(x[:-1]):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use double slicing like this

```
for i in x[::-1][1:]:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

can reverse after removing for the loop:

```
for i in x[:-1][::1]:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers that involve list slicing are probably best, but it could also be done with enumerate.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for index, value in enumerate(reversed(x)):
    val = value-1
    if val:
        print(val)
```

Again, the slicing answers are better in a "Big O" sense, but it doesn't hurt to see a few ways to do a thing.